# Flatten/Group the list of values/elements in json file under one column

Tags: python, json, list, dataframe, parsing

Could you please tell me if there is an easy and clean way to flatten the following json as below: Parsing and looping over and writing is one option using json dumps and loads. Looking for if there is any build-in/useful function/package/tools. One problem with regular flattening function is that, if the size of values of the key3 is too much(i.e to many values value11, value11, value33....) then number of columns will be a lot. Hence I want to avoid that. One other option is to introduce a key for those values (i.e change the structure of json before processing it)

input Json:

```
     {   key1 : value1,
         key2 : value2,
         key3 : { value11 : [{id:a1, name: b1}],
                  value22 : [{id:a2, name: b2},{id:a4, name: b4}],
                  value33 : [{id:a3, name: b3}],
         ...
                }
       }
```

Output Dataframe

```
col_1   | col_2  | col_3    | id | name 
value1  | value2 |  value11 | a1 |  b1
value1  | value2 |  value22 | a2 |  b2
value1  | value2 |  value22 | a4 |  b4
value1  | value2 |  value33 | a3 |  b3
```

}

Comment: your data requires custom code, I do not think there is any built-in tool for your case

Comment: the last value for the column `name` should be  `b3` ?

Comment: @kederrac yes, thanks, I corrected.